# react-redux areStatesEqual never fires

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I am trying to limit the amount of times react-rexdux connect() fires re-renders.  I've looked at the documentation here...

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

... and supposedly there is a way to prevent re-renders by writing your own config option function for areStatesEqual.  The problem is, my simple console.log test shows that this option never fires!  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  There is not a lot of documentation on this feature, not even one example.

```
export const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => Object.assign({
  isMobileLayout: state.deviceWidthReducer.width < 480,
  postalCode: state.userReducer.postalCode,
  productImageGroup: state.productReducer.productImageGroup,
  productId: '05047234',
}, ownProps);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
  null,
  {
    pure: true,
    areStatesEqual: (next, prev) => {
      console.log('areStatesEqual?'); // <-- THIS NEVER GETS LOGGED.
      return next.productId === prev.productId;
    },
  },
)(Product);
```

Setting a breakpoint in dev tools, the breakpoint is never fired either.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/592 - this can be related/explaining a bit or missleading ;)

Try `undefined` instead of `null`? But I don't know it matters.

Use 'standard' `shouldComponentUpdate` optimizations?